# Documenting nested serializer at api root of DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I try to document post endpoint of api. The serializer of this view is `ParentSerializer` which is a composition of `ChildSerializer`.

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  name = serializers.CharField()
  surname = serializer.CharField()

class ParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  children = ChildSerializer(many=True)
```

---

Next in my viewset I implemented `get_serializer` method to make model appear in api root documentation.

```
class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get_serializer(self):
        return ParentSerializer()

    def create(self, request):
        # ... do something ...
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

---

I expected that model in documentation will be nested serializer but it only shows parent attributes.

So the documented model looks like:

```
{
    "children": []
}
```

Can I somehow tell the api user what is the model of `"children"` key? What would be the best way to provide examples and model of expected request data?

Comment: the `children` should be real name of the attribute your parent model, please add models if uou need more details.

Comment: Do I need models to document endpoint requested data? Especially when serializers are not ModelSerializer clas

Comment: if serializers are not for models, you should show how you create initial data for them.